# Form error after switching to Django 1.9 from Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, forms, upgrade

I have the following form...it worked perfectly in Django 1.8, but not now in Django 1.9. I uninstalled registration redux so IDK if that would affect it but I wouldn't think so. Anyway I have the following code:

```
def save(self,datas,commit=True,):
    user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save()
    user.first_name=self.cleaned_data['fname']
    user.last_name=self.cleaned_data['lname']
    # user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    user.username = self.cleaned_data['email']
    # user.is_active=False
    # permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can view poll') 
    # u.user_permissions.add(permission)
    user.save()

    r_user = RegisterUser(user=user,biography="default1", research_place="default2", studies="default3")
    if commit:
        r_user.activation_key = datas['activation_key']
        r_user.key_expires=datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        r_user.save()
        # print ('saving user: %s' % self.user)
    return r_user

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
    try:
        user.objects.get(username=username)
    except user.DoesNotExist:
        return username
    raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])
```

And I get the error that 'user' is not defined in clean_username. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `user` instead of `User` you want to `User.objects.get(...`) same for `User.DoesNotExist`.

You want the `User` model from `django.auth.models`

Comment: Ok, thanks.. Why did it work in Django 1.8? I thought I was referencing     user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save()

Comment: `user = super(RegistrationForm, ...` is an instance, which you defined to be `user` so you could access attributes from this instance, but you don't have a `user` variable defined anywhere in `clean_username` as you see in the error message